# Building a unique array of db fields

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is stripped down from a project I'm working on:

```
let userFields = {
    id: {
        dbFields: 'id',
    },
    email: {
        dbFields: 'email',
    },
    first_name: {
        dbFields: 'first_name',
    },
    last_name: {
        dbFields: 'last_name',
    },
    name: {
        dbFields: ['first_name', 'last_name'],
        resolve: user => [user.first_name, user.last_name].filter(n => n.length).join(' '),
    }
};

let selectFields = ['name', 'first_name', 'email'];

let dbFields = new Set();
selectFields.forEach(f => {
    if(userFields[f].dbFields) {
        if(userFields[f].dbFields instanceof Array) {
            userFields[f].dbFields.forEach(x => dbFields.add(x));
        } else {
            dbFields.add(userFields[f].dbFields);
        }
    }
});

console.log(Array.from(dbFields)); // [ 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email' ]
```

I don't like that big `selectFields.forEach` or the fact that [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) doesn't appear to have an `addMany` method.

Is there any way I can compact this a bit more?

You can run this with babel-node if you need to (`npm install -g babel`).

Comment: Here's an idea: http://pastebin.com/T8pqrVZ0

Comment: LGTM. I basically don't see a way to make it more compact without getting intricate or doing something kind of strange. Some small changes: http://jsfiddle.net/66svv9pe/

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of [Array​.prototype​.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
 we might compact this a bit.

Basically, we filter all of our fields, making them an array if they are not already, getting out an array of arrays (nested only one level). After that, we can easily flatten it, so we iterate each element and we can just add it to our set.

```js
let userFields = {
    id: {
        dbFields: 'id',
    },
    email: {
        dbFields: 'email',
    },
    first_name: {
        dbFields: 'first_name',
    },
    last_name: {
        dbFields: 'last_name',
    },
    name: {
        dbFields: ['first_name', 'last_name'],
        resolve: user => [user.first_name, user.last_name].filter(n => n.length).join(' '),
    }
};

let selectFields = ['name', 'first_name', 'email'];

let dbFields = new Set();
selectFields.map(key => {
    let field = userFields[key].dbFields;
    return (field instanceof Array) ? field : [field]
  })
  .flat()
  .forEach(v => dbFields.add(v));
console.log(Array.from(dbFields));
```

Comment: Even better, we can use [`flatMap`](http://go/mdn/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: I would have to review it, I am unsure how it works if not all elements inside the array are arrays

Comment: I tried it. Seems to work well whether or not you do `Array.isArray(field) ? field : [field]`. That simplifies the loop to: `selectFields.flatMap(key => userFields[key].dbFields).forEach(v => dbFields.add(v));`

Comment: Or even more fun: `const dbFields = selectFields.flatMap(key => userFields[key].dbFields).reduce((s,v) => s.add(v), new Set);`